# Color fade on hover not working on safari

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm experiencing an odd bug.
Even with -webkit-transition included, color fades on safari aren't seeming to work for me. Works fine on chrome. Also, I'm using NextJS, hence the  inside of the .

The color does change on hover, but only on chrome does it actually fade. On safari it's just a quick switch.

Heres a segment from my CSS

```
.socialThird{
@include flex-center();
height: 100%;


.iconA{ // anchor tag
    height:50%;
    width: 75px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    padding: 10px 8px;

    .emailSVG{ // svg 
        fill: #333;
        filter: drop-shadow( 0 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
        -o-filter:drop-shadow( 0 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
        -ms-filter:drop-shadow( 0 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
        -moz-filter:drop-shadow( 0 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
        -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
        -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
        -o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
        transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%;

        &:hover{
            fill: #00bcc5;
        }
    }

    &:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: translate(0px, -6px);
    }
}
```

}

Hopefully this was enough information, thanks!

Comment: I don't have access to Safari, sadly, but can you try and see what happens if you change the `transition: all [etc]` to `transition: fill [etc]`?

Comment: It doesn't work sadly. I've heard that "all" does act weird on safari but alas, does not fix it.

Comment: Aw, sorry man. I don't have any other ideas :(